# Unable to Append Array Within MongoDB (mongoose) Document

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to append an empty array in a mongo database with a String that is created in the front-end (website ui), the relevant code snipets are as following:

mongoose Schema

```
    email: String,
    displayName: String,
    googleId: String,
    toIgnore: [{toIgnoreURL: String}]
})
```

document creation with passport & passport-google-oauth20

```
User.findOne({email: email.emails[0].value}).then((currentUser)=>{
            if(currentUser){
                // user does already exist
                console.log('welcome back!', currentUser)
                done(null, currentUser)
            }
            else{ // user doesn't exist yet
            new User({
                email: email.emails[0].value,
                displayName: email.displayName,
                googleId: email.id,
                toIgnore: []
            }).save().then((newUser)=>{
                console.log('new user created: ' + newUser)
                done(null, newUser)
            });
            }
        })
```

And lastly the attempt to append the toIgnore array property of the 'User' collection (of the currently logged in user)

```
User.update(
        {email: emailThisSession},
        {$push: {toIgnore: {toIgnoreURL: url}}})
```

In mongodb I see that the following document is successfully created

```
_id
:ObjectId(
IdOfDocumentInMongoDB)
toIgnore
:
Array
email
:
"myactualtestemail"
googleId
:
"longgoogleidonlynumbers"
__v
:
0
```

(Also as seen in attached image)
[document in mongodb ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snq5X.png)

I don't seem to figure out how to actually populate the 'toIgnore' array.
For instance, when console logging the following

```
var ignoreList = User.findOne({email:emailThisSession}).toIgnore;
console.log(ignoreList)
```

The output is `undefined`
Note that console logging the url variable does indeed print the value I want to append to the array!
I tried any format combination I could think of in the Schema builder and document creation, but I can't find figure the right way to get it done!
Any help would be appreciated!

Update, using promises didn't work either

```
User.findOne({email:emailThisSession}).then((currentUser)=>{ //adding .exec() after findOne({query}) does not help as in User.findOne({email:emailThisSession}).exec().then(...)
            console.log(currentUser.toIgnore, url) //output is empty array and proper value for url variable, empty array meaning []
            currentUser.toIgnore.push(url)
        });
```

While adjusting the Schema as follows:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    displayName: String,
    googleId: String,
    toIgnore: []
})
```

**Solution**

I simply needed to change the update command to

```
User.updateOne(
            {email: emailThisSession},
            {$push: {toIgnore: {toIgnoreURL: url}}}).then((user)=>{
                console.log(user)
            })
```

Thanks @yaya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to add array element within a document with mongoose

1. define your schema as:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  toIgnore: [{toIgnoreURL: String}]
})
```

2. then you can create an object like this :

```
new User({
  ...,
  toIgnore: [] // <-- optional, you can remove it
})
```

3. To check the value:

```
User.findOne({...}).then(user => {
  console.log(user.toIgnore)
});
```

4. Your update statement should be:

```
User.update(
  {email: emailThisSession},
  {$push: {toIgnore: {toIgnoreURL: url}}}
).then(user => {
  console.log(user)
})
```

---

So in your case, this is undefined:

```
User.findOne({email:emailThisSession}).toIgnore
```

Since `findOne` is async. for getting the result, you can whether pass it a callback or you can use promises (`User.findOne({...}).then(user => console.log(user.toIgnore))`)

Update:

> While adjusting the Schema as follows: `new Schema({..., toIgnore: []})`

Here is the problem with your update. you should change it back to : `toIgnore: [{toIgnoreURL: String}]`

Comment: @Hope2Code there is a problem in your update. updated the answer.

Comment: I did manage to print an empty array, as in the ignore list by the code
```var ignoreList = User.findOne({email:emailThisSession}).then((currentUser)=>{
            console.log(currentUser.toIgnore, url)
            currentUser.toIgnore.push(url)
        });```
But I still can't append the array with .push

Comment: @Hope2Code see the update. you're schema is incorrect, so it doesn't save the updated value. first correct your schema, then call the `update user` again to let it save the updated value again.

Comment: @Hope2Code now i can see another problem. `User.update(...)` doesn't get executed , you should exec it manually. for example with : `User.update(...).then(user => {console.log(user)})` or with `.exec()`

Comment: @Hope2Code schema is correct. but updateOne is not.`then` means `execute the statement and get the result.`. so it should be:  `User.updateOne( {email: emailThisSession}, {$push: {toIgnore: {toIgnoreURL: url}}}).then((user)=>{console.log('done', user)})`

Comment: @Hope2Code schema is incorrect also: `[{text: String}]` should be: `[{toIgnoreURL: String}]`

Comment: I think it solved it!!!!! :D
It appears as the following image, which I hope is the correct representation of an array in mongoDB
https://imgur.com/a/jtSrHa6


```User.updateOne(
            {email: emailThisSession},
            {$push: {toIgnore: {toIgnoreURL: url}}}).then((user)=>{
                console.log(user)
            })```

Comment: @Hope2Code No problem, i think it's ok. you can also try this way for declaring schema : `toIgnore: [new Schema({toIgnoreURL: String})]`. i'm not totally sure but i think this way it will store them as documents, not simple objects. (currently yo're storing them as simple objects. they don't have ids.) . also please put the solution at the end of your question as an `edit`, not at top.